# Linked List function to sort in c

Tags: c, linked-list

I am suppose to edit the insertSortedLL linked list function

After I inserted the code,it appears that my linked list printed out is in opposite matter eg Output: 5 4 3 2 1
I want the output to print 1 2 3 4 5
Basically the question is how to sort the linked list value

```
int insertSortedLL(LinkedList *ll, int item)
{
  insertNode(ll, 0,item);
  printList(ll);
}

void printList(LinkedList *ll) {

ListNode *cur;
if (ll == NULL)
    return;
cur = ll->head;

if (cur == NULL)
    printf("Empty");
while (cur != NULL)
{
    printf("%d ", cur->item);
    cur = cur->next;
}
printf("\n");
}

void removeAllItems(LinkedList *ll)
{
ListNode *cur = ll->head;
ListNode *tmp;

while (cur != NULL) {
    tmp = cur->next;
    free(cur);
    cur = tmp;
}
ll->head = NULL;
ll->size = 0;
}

ListNode * findNode(LinkedList *ll, int index) {

ListNode *temp;

if (ll == NULL || index < 0 || index >= ll->size)
    return NULL;

temp = ll->head;

if (temp == NULL || index < 0)
    return NULL;

while (index > 0) {
    temp = temp->next;
    if (temp == NULL)
        return NULL;
    index--;
}

return temp;
}

int insertNode(LinkedList *ll, int index, int value) {

ListNode *pre, *cur;

if (ll == NULL || index < 0 || index > ll->size + 1)
    return -1;

// If empty list or inserting first node, need to update head pointer
if (ll->head == NULL || index == 0) {
    cur = ll->head;
    ll->head = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    ll->head->item = value;
    ll->head->next = cur;
    ll->size++;
    return 0;
}

// Find the nodes before and at the target position
// Create a new node and reconnect the links
if ((pre = findNode(ll, index - 1)) != NULL) {
    cur = pre->next;
    pre->next = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    pre->next->item = value;
    pre->next->next = cur;
    ll->size++;
    return 0;
}

return -1;
}

int removeNode(LinkedList *ll, int index) {

ListNode *pre, *cur;

// Highest index we can remove is size-1
if (ll == NULL || index < 0 || index >= ll->size)
    return -1;

// If removing first node, need to update head pointer
if (index == 0) {
    cur = ll->head->next;
    free(ll->head);
    ll->head = cur;
    ll->size--;

    return 0;
}

// Find the nodes before and after the target position
// Free the target node and reconnect the links
if ((pre = findNode(ll, index - 1)) != NULL) {

    if (pre->next == NULL)
        return -1;

    cur = pre->next;
    pre->next = cur->next;
    free(cur);
    ll->size--;
    return 0;
}

return -1;
}
```

Comment: How and where do you call `insertSortedLL`? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, and remove the functions that aren't relevant to your question (like the function to remove nodes). And there's really no "sorting" going on that I can see, only that `insertSortedLL` always insert at position `0`.

Comment: The way this code is organised, it inserts any new node at index 0, so it's up you to insert the node in the correct order (aka start with 5, then 4, 3, 2 and finish with 1). Your list would be sorted.

However, I think you want an algorithm that finds the right index, and then inserts the node at the correct place.

Comment: did u try stepping through the code with a debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `insertSortedLL()` function should insert a node into a sorted list at the correct location. If you build a list using this function, the resulting list will be sorted.

Your `insertSortedLL()` function needs to traverse the list, comparing the `item` at each node with the `item` that you want to insert. The item is inserted in the location of the first node containing a value larger than the insertion value, or at the end of the list. Here is an example of how this might be written:

```
int insertSortedLL(LinkedList *ll, int item)
{
    ListNode *cur = ll->head;
    int ll_size = ll->size;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= ll_size; i++) {
        if ((ll_size - i) == 0 || item < cur->item) {
            insertNode(ll, i, item);
            return 0;
        }
        cur = cur->next;
    }

    return -1;
}
```